# Dynamically added buttons don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I can't seem to figure out why when I create a new div with a button in it, the button will not respond to the click function I assign it. I'm sure I've just got the syntax messed up somehow. Ideally when I click the "New Category" button, a new category div will be made within the Topic div that it's contained in, but it won't even respond to an alert function.

```
$(":button.Topic").click(function (event) {
    $("body").append(TopicDiv);
});

//when Category class button is clicked, append Category Div to parent of button clicked
$("button").on("click", function () {
    alert("Hello!");
    /*$( this ).parentNode.append(CategoryDiv);*/
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KrsVp/5/

Comment: @Zenith: I know, I tried searching but I couldn't seem to make the previous answers work with my code. Admittedly this was a selfish question, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", ":button.Category", function () {
    alert("Hello!");
    /*$( this ).parentNode.append(CategoryDiv);*/
});
```

the idea is that you let a parent element listen to the event, then let it check if any children match the `:button.Category` selector.

The closest the parent, the best the performance [i.e. don't use `document` if possible].

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like:

```
$("button").on("click", ...
```

You are attaching an event handler to any elements that match that selector. Dynamically added elements dont exist yet when that line of code is executed, so those elements wont have your event handler attached.

However, when you do something like:

```
$(document).on("click", "button", ...
```

You are attaching the event handler to the document element and delegating the event to any button elements inside it, this ensures that dynamically added elements will still trigger this handler correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your buttons are not added to the DOM yet.  Your code only creates the DIV's when when the OTHER DIV's child button is clicked.  However, neither DIV or their children button exists.  So, neither DIV exists to be clicked.  And, if the DIV was present at the DOM's ready state you need to attached the click even to added DIV's button.